# How to make an analog clock in f# using winforms and make it move?

Tags: winforms, f#, real-time, clock

I have to create an analog clock using winforms in f#. The clock also needs to have a label showing time and date in digital form. I have figured out how to make the label and drawing the clock with the hands included, but the tricky part is to center it all and make the clock-hands move. I got both the rotate and the translate function from my school book and was encouraged to use. I've seen some other examples of the same code and it is almost identical to my own, but I can't seem to find the answer to my question anywhere. Is there any1 who can help me on my way?

```
open System  
open System.Windows.Forms  
open System.ComponentModel  
open System.Drawing  

// ********* Winforms specs *********
let win = new Form()
win.ClientSize <- Size (500, 500)

/// ********* Digital Clock *********
// make a label to show time
let digitalTimerLabel = new Label ()
win.Controls.Add digitalTimerLabel
digitalTimerLabel.Width <- 200
digitalTimerLabel.Location <- new Point (140,300)
digitalTimerLabel.Text <- string System.DateTime.Now // get present time and date

// make a timer and link to label
let timer = new Timer ()
timer.Interval <- 1000 // create an event every 1000 millisecond
timer.Enabled <- true // activiate the timer
timer.Tick.Add (fun e ->
digitalTimerLabel.Text <- string System.DateTime.Now
win.Invalidate()
)

// ********* Translate the clock *********
let translate (d : Point) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
    let add (d : Point) (p : Point) : Point =
        Point (d.X + p.X, d.Y + p.Y)
    Array.map (add d) arr

// ********* Rotate the clock hands *********
let rotate (theta : float) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
        let toInt = int << round
        let rot (t : float) (p : Point) : Point =
            let (x, y) = (float p.X, float p.Y)
            let (a, b) = (x * cos t - y * sin t, x * sin t + y * cos t)
            Point (toInt a, toInt b)
        Array.map (rot theta) arr

/// ********* ClockHands *********
let myPaint (e : PaintEventArgs) : unit =
    // HourHand
    let black = new Pen (Color.Black,Width=2.0f)
    let hourHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-45)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (black, hourHand)

    // MinuteHand
    let red = new Pen (Color.Red,Width=4.0f)
    let minuteHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-20)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (red, minuteHand)

    // SecondHand
    let green = new Pen (Color.Green,Width=1.0f)
    let secondHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-20)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (green, secondHand)

    // Circle
    let circleBlack = new Pen(Color.Black,Width=4.0f)
    let circle =
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circleBlack, 50.0f,50.0f,400.0f,400.0f)
    circle

    // CenterDot
    let CenterDotBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    let center =
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CenterDotBrush,-2.5f,-2.5f,5.0f,5.0f)
    center

    let dt = DateTime.Now
    let s = dt.Second
    let m = dt.Minute
    let h = dt.Hour
    let newS = rotate (float s/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) secondHand
    let newM = rotate (float m/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) minuteHand
    let newH = rotate (float h/12.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) hourHand
    let finalS = translate (Point (200, 200)) secondHand
    let finalM = translate (Point (200, 200)) minuteHand
    let finalH = translate (Point (200, 200)) hourHand
    ()

win.Paint.Add myPaint

Application.Run win // start event - loop
```

Comment: What is the difference from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301434/how-do-i-create-an-analog-clock-using-winforms-in-f)?